# Binding an array in polymer and detecting changes in a child component

Tags: arrays, data-binding, polymer

I have a component in Polymer that has an array as one of its properties.

Then I have a child component to which I'm passing this array. What I'm trying to do is to detect a change in that array from the child component.

Here is the parent component:

```
<dom-module id="some-test">

  <template>

    <paper-input label="Let's update param" on-input="updateParam"></paper-input>
    <some-child param={{param}}></some-child>

  </template>

  <script>
    Polymer({
      is: 'some-test',
      properties: {
          param: {type: Array, value: []}
      },
      updateParam: function(e) {
         this.param["test"] = e.currentTarget.value;
         console.log("Param has been updated");
      }
    });
  </script>

</dom-module>
```

And here is the child component:

```
<dom-module id="some-child">

  <template>
      <div>the child component</div>
  </template>

  <script>
    Polymer({
      is: 'some-child',
      properties: {
        param: {type: Array, observer: "doSomething"},
      },
      doSomething: function() {
        console.log("ah, we've detected a change in param");
      },
    });
  </script>

</dom-module>
```

So, when I type something in the input field (in the first component), I get a consolge log of "Param has been updated". All good.

But then I would except param to be passed to the child component, which would detect the change and log "ah, we've detected a change in param".

However this doesn't seem to happen. If I use a string instead of an array, then it works as intended. But if it's an array and I update one of its values, the child component doesn't pick up the change.

This leads me to believe I am missing something as to how to bind an array. Any clues?

Comment: I think you're missing `notify:true` in your params property for two-way data binding to work.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Unfortunately adding "notify:true" doesn't seem to make it work.

Comment: Also, it works if I use a string rather than a table, so that's why I think it has to do with how Polymer handles tables. I've read all the docs and tried a few variations (such as for example `this.set('this.param.test, e.currentTarget.value)`), but still can't seem to figure it out.

Comment: Anyone would have any ideas on how to solve that? (in other words, how to get a child component to detect a change in an array that's in the parent component?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah, I finally got it working! It took a combination of the various answers. Here is the final code that works:

Parent component:

```
<dom-module id="some-test">

  <template>

    <paper-input label="Let's update param" on-input="updateParam"></paper-input>
    <some-child param={{param}}></some-child>

  </template>

  <script>
    Polymer({
      is: 'some-test',
      properties: {
          param: {type: Array, value: []}
      },
      updateParam: function(e) {
         this.set("param.test", e.currentTarget.value); <!-- this is the first trick -->
         console.log("Param has been updated");
      }
    });
  </script>

</dom-module>
```

And here is the child component:

```
<dom-module id="some-child">

  <template>
      <div>the child component</div>
  </template>

  <script>
    Polymer({
      is: 'some-child',
      properties: {
        param: {type: Array},
      },
      observers: [
        "doSomething(param.*)"
      ]
      doSomething: function() {
        console.log("ah, we've detected a change in param");
      },
    });
  </script>

</dom-module>
```

So, the two things that I needed to do were:
1) Use "this.set()" to update the value of the object in the parent component
2) Use a complex observer in the child component

Answer (score 2):

You can use complex observers in child components:

```
<dom-module id="some-child">

  <template>
      <div>the child component</div>
  </template>

  <script>
    Polymer({
      is: 'some-child',
      properties: {
        param: {type: Array, observer: "doSomething"},
      },

      //Here add complex observers
      observers: ['doSomething(param.*)', 'doSomething(param.splices)'],

      doSomething: function() {
        console.log("ah, we've detected a change in param");
      },
    });
  </script>

</dom-module>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, you got me on the right track! I think the syntax for complex observers is slightly different, but the combination of using those as well as this.set() did the trick